# Why the validation doesn't work at all the code in javascript even when I don't write the name it doesn't alert anything

Tags: javascript, html, function, validation, passwords

It worked but I don't know what happened that now it is not working. Maybe I have the problem in my other piece of code. I have the javascript in the `head` and html in the `body` area

1. Not working javascript validation

   - even when I submit without writing my name, it doesn't alert me.

     - or other fields.
2. Check box validation not working

```js
function valid() {

  var fname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
  if (fname == "") {
    alert("Shkruani emrin");
    document.getElementById("fname");
    return false;
  }
  var lname = document.getElementById("lname").value;
  if (lname == "") {
    alert("Enter Lastname");
    document.getElementById("lname");
    return false;
  }
  var birthdat = document.getElementById("birthdat").value;
  if (birthdat == "") {
    alert("Enter birthday");
    document.getElementById("birthdat");
    return false;
  }
  var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
  if (email == "") {
    alert("Enter email");
    document.getElementById("email").focus();
    return false;
  }
  var atpos = email.indexOf("@");
  var dotpos = email.lastIndexOf(".");
  if (atpos < 0 || dotpos < atpos + 1 || dotpos + 1 >= email.length) {
    alert("Nuk eshte e-mail adrese valide");
    return false;
  }
  var check = document.getElementById("thebox").checked;
  if (check) {
    alert("Thank you!");
  } else {
    alert("Are you a robot not checked!");
    document.getElementById("thebox");
    return false;
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <form name=formac onsubmit="return valid();" method="post" autocomplete="on">
    <fieldset><label for="fname">First Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name.." autocomplete="off">
      <br>
      <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last name..">
      <br>
      <label for="birthday">Birthday </label>
      <input type="text" id="birthdat" pattern="(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[01]).(0[1-9]|1[012]).[0-9]{4}" title="Day.Moth.Year" name="birthday" placeholder="Your date of birth.." style="margin-left: 17px;">
      <br>
      <label for="email">Email </label>
      <input type="email" id="email" name="emailadsdres" placeholder="Your email address..">
      <br>
      <label for="phone">Phone 
            <input type="tel" id="phone"  pattern="[0-9]{1}[0-9]{9}" name="phone" placeholder="Your phone number.." title="10 digit phone eg:1234569877" autocomplete="off" required >
        <br>
            <label for="city">City </label>
      <select id="city" name="city">
             <datalist> <option value="zurich">Zurich</option>
              <option value="geneva">Geneva</option>
              <option value="basel">Basel</option>
              <option value="bern">Bern</option>
              <option value="lugano">Lugano</option>
              <option value="vernier">Vernier</option>
              <option value="uster">Uster</option>   
              <option value="thun">Thun</option>   
              <option value="sior">Sior</option>   
        </datalist>
            </select>
      <br>
      <p> Are you a robot?

        <input type="checkbox" id="thebox" name="thebox"> I'm not a robot.<br>
      </p>
      <br>
      <textarea id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Write something.." style="height:70px"></textarea>
      <button type="button" id="btn1">Great</button>
      <button type="button" id="btn2">Good</button>
      <button type="button" id="btn3">Bad</button>

      <br>
      <input style="outline-style:inset; outline-offset: 10px;" type="submit" value="Submit" onsubmit="return valid();">

    </fieldset>
  </form>
```

Comment: an aside: `dotpos+1>=email.length`, should this not be written as `dotpos >= email.length - 1` ?

Comment: This line has a bug `if (phone == "" || phone =  null) {` should be `if (phone == "" || phone == null) {`

Comment: I moved your code into a code snippet, but did not correct the error I mentioned above.  I did, however, change your comment marking the line causing your issue, into a true comment with `//`

Comment: (.. the edit will be visible, once it passes the edit review process.)

Comment: When you run the code snippet the Error message that appears is referencing the error above.  Simply add the missing `=` to fix that error.

To keep in line with SO policy editing an OP's code, it would not be proper for *me* to fix the typo in your code.

Comment: @SherylHohman I actually  deleted that part of the code because I used inline pattern  for phone and if I left it(the phone validation) ,the check box would always pop up the "Thank you" if checked or " Are you a robot not checked!" if not checked so if I don't write the email for example it would alert me to enter email and for the check box  at once.
So I deleted the phone validation and moved the check box validation at the bottom of JS  code, also all the code of JS at the end, just before the body closing tag like someone suggested here and it works perfectly.

Comment: Regardless, the code posted in the question has a bug, that is not related to your question. If someone comes here looking for an answer and copies this code, it won't work, but not for reasons indicated in the question. They will waste time trying to debug it (as *I* did)! I recommend either fixing the unrelated bug/typo, or removing irrelevant code. Actually..read up on [MVE: Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) --*deleting code unnecessary to the particular question asked is **always** recommended*.  Anyway, Glad you found your answer. Welcome to SO !

Comment: @SherylHohman I made some changes in the code and thanks for the recomandation I will delete the code if it still doesn't work.

Comment: Excellent! I fixed the code snippet formatting, so it runs properly as an embedded snippet.  It's just awaiting peer review now.  Thanks for your contribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try with the following code:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <form name=formac onsubmit="return valid();" method="post" autocomplete="on">
    <fieldset><label for="fname">First Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name.." autocomplete="off">
      <br>
      <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last name..">
      <br>
      <label for="birthday">Birthday </label>
      <input type="text" id="birthdat" pattern="(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[01]).(0[1-9]|1[012]).[0-9]{4}" title="Day.Moth.Year" name="birthday" placeholder="Your date of birth.." style="margin-left: 17px;">
      <br>
      <label for="email">Email </label>
      <input type="email" id="email" name="emailadsdres" placeholder="Your email address..">
      <br>
      <label for="phone">Phone 
        <input type="tel" id="phone"  pattern="[0-9]{1}[0-9]{9}" name="phone" placeholder="Your phone number.." title="10 digit phone eg:1234569877" autocomplete="off">
    <br>
        <label for="city">City </label>
      <select id="city" name="city">
         <datalist> <option value="zurich">Zurich</option>
          <option value="geneva">Geneva</option>
          <option value="basel">Basel</option>
          <option value="bern">Bern</option>
          <option value="lugano">Lugano</option>
          <option value="vernier">Vernier</option>
          <option value="uster">Uster</option>   
          <option value="thun">Thun</option>   
          <option value="sior">Sior</option>   
    </datalist>
        </select>
      <br>
      <p> Are you a robot?

        <input type="checkbox" id="thebox" name="thebox"> I'm not a robot.<br>
      </p>
      <br>
      <textarea id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Write something.." style="height:70px"></textarea>
      <button type="button" id="btn1">Great</button>
      <button type="button" id="btn2">Good</button>
      <button type="button" id="btn3">Bad</button>

      <br>
      <input style="outline-style:inset; outline-offset: 10px;" type="submit" value="Submit">

    </fieldset>
  </form>

  <label>Optional email</label><input type="text" name="" form="formac"></div>
<table style="width:100%">
<script>
 function valid() {
  var check = document.getElementById("thebox").checked; //>not working
  if (check) {
    alert("Thank you!");
  } else {
    alert("Are you a robot not checked!");
    document.getElementById("thebox");
    return false;
  }
  var fname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
  if (fname == "") {
    alert("Shkruani emrin");
    document.getElementById("fname");
    return false;
  }
  var lname = document.getElementById("lname").value;
  if (lname == "") {
    alert("Enter Lastname");
    document.getElementById("lname");
    return false;
  }
  var birthdat = document.getElementById("birthdat").value;
  if (birthdat == "") {
    alert("Enter birthday");
    document.getElementById("phone");
    return false;
  }
  var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
  if (email == "") {
    alert("Enter email");
    document.getElementById("email").focus();
    return false;
  }
  var atpos = email.indexOf("@");
  var dotpos = email.lastIndexOf(".");
  if (atpos < 0 || dotpos < atpos + 1 || dotpos + 1 >= email.length) {
    alert("Nuk eshte e-mail adrese valide");
    return false;
  }
  var phone = document.getElementById("phone").value;
  if (!phone) {
    alert("Enter the phone number ");
    document.getElementById("phone").focus();
    return false;
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your JavaScript at the bottom of the page just before the end body tag. This way the rest of the page has been loaded before you attempt to perform any operations.